# stream video from panda board to IPhone

Tags: c++

I am using panda board and i have installed opencv and wrote a code for sticking 3 different images from 3 different cams.now this stitched image is stored in a matrix location(pointer).i for that 3 cams images will be continuously captured and stitched.so it becomes a video.so i need to stream that stitched image to iPhone .can any one help me with this.i am really stuck here and need help.its very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at constructing either mjpeg stream or better a RTSP (encapsulating mpeg4 - saving bandwidth) stream based on RTP protocol. Say you decide to go with mjpeg stream, then each of your opencv IplImage* can be converted to JPEG Frames using libjpeg compression. See my answer here [Compressing IplImage to JPEG using libjpeg in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443390/compressing-iplimage-to-jpeg-using-libjpeg-in-opencv/2602452#2602452). You would compress each frame and then create mjpeg stream. See [creating my own MJPEG stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595945/creating-my-own-mjpeg-stream). You would need a webserver to run mjpeg cgi that streams your image stream. You could look at lighttpd web server running on Panda Board. Gstreamer is the package that may be helpful in your situation. On the decoding side (iphone) you can construct gstreamer decoding pipeline as follows - say you are streaming mjpeg `gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location="http://<ip>:<port>/cgi_bin/<mjpegcginame>.cgi" do-timestamp=true is_live=true ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink`